# How to display tooltip on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add tooltip on a card. I am trying to make this work like- "When I hover on a bootstrap card another card will show on tooltip". I am using bootstrap 4 for my project.
This is the main card. If i hover next card will show on tooltip. Is it possible? Please help me with my project.

```css
.card {
    border: 0 !important;
}
.card .card-img-top {
    border: 1px solid #dcdacb;
    border-radius: 7px;
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
}
.card .card-img-top:hover {
    filter: #dcdacb;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-body {
    padding: 1.25rem 0 !important;
}

.card-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: -.02rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    color: #3c3b37;
    margin: -0.7rem 0px 0.75rem 0 !important;
}

.card .seller-name {
    margin: -0.5rem 0 0 0;
    color: #73726c;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.card .card-rating-number {
    color: #be5a0e;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: -.02rem;
    font-size: 0.9rem;

}

.card .fa-star,
.card .fa-star-half-alt {
    color: #eb8a2f;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.card .price {
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: -.02rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.card .price del {
    color: #73726c;
}

.card .total-sale {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: #73726c;
}

.card .best-seller {
    background-color: #ffe799;
    color: #593d00;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.3em;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/BFMMlbcQvml9HSqXcvNp" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Natural Language Processing with Deep Learning in Python</h4>
                            <div class="card-text">
                                <h6 class="seller-name">Boyeong Kang</h6>
                                <div class="card-rating">
                                    <span class="card-rating-number">4.5 </span>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                                    <span class="total-sale">(123,456)</span>
                                    <h3 class="price">120$ &nbsp; <del>150$</del></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="best-seller">Best Seller</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the card that I want on tooltip.

```css
table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

table td i {
    margin-top: 0.4rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="card" style="max-width:350px">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Python for Data Science and Machine Learning Bootcamp</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Learn how to use NumPy, Pandas, Seaborn , Matplotlib , Plotly , Scikit-Learn , Machine Learning,
                    Tensorflow , and more!
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        <td>Use Python for Data Science and Machine Learning</li>
                    <tr>
                        <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                        <td>Use Spark for Big Data Analysis</li>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                        <td>Implement Machine Learning Algorithms</li>
                        </td>
                </table>
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you might create the titles. It's fairly easy from that point to apply jQueryUI Tooltips, which allow custom styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/G38nx/25

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please, Could you give me a simple example? Your code is too complicated for me.

Comment: *too complicated*?  It's literally **two lines** `$(this).attr('title', myTitle); $(this).tooltip();`  the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please include all (and only) *relevant* code in the answer, ideally in a working snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`) that demonstrates the code.

Comment: Can you give a example using 2nd card? It would be very helpfull for me.